# How to import class from external assembly to Visual Studio Text Editor Extension?

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, vsix

I am trying to develop a text editor extension for Visual Studio 2017, and I have a trouble to import a class instance defined in an external assembly to IWpfTextEditorCreationListener's constructor. If I try to import a class defined in an external assembly into the constructor, IWpfTextEditorCreationListener is not triggered.

The extension implements IWpfTextEditorCreationListener interface like the following code:

```
    [ContentType("code")]
    [Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
    [TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
    public class MyTextViewCreationListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
    {
        private ExternalClassLibrary.ExternalClass clazz;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MyTextViewCreationListener(ExternalClassLibrary.ExternalClass clazz)
        {
             this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
        {
            clazz.foo();
        }
    }
```

The ExternalClass is implemented in another assembly as follow:

```
namespace ExternalClassLibrary
{
    [Export]
    public class ExternalClass
    {
        public void foo()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If the constructor of MyTextViewCreationListener is commented out, TextViewCreated() is called, but it is not commented out, TextViewCreated() is not called.
Is it possible to import external assemblies to the IWpfTextViewCreationListener?

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Did you check Visual Studio activity log for any error related to your package? Also, how are you bundling this external assembly?

Comment: Why you are using MEF for your assemblies? Can you create instantiate ExternalClass in code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

1. Open the source extension.vsixmanifest file in the VSIX project.
2. On the Assets tab, add the external assembly as MefComponent.

   1. Click the New button
   2. In the Type list, choose the Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent.
   3. In the Source list, choose the A project in current solution.
   4. In the Project list, choose the external assembly you want to import to the VSIX project.

I uploaded an examble to [GitHub](https://github.com/DaisukeAtaraxiA/VSIXImportExternalAssemblyExample).